# Remap Sublime Text 2 Ctrl-Q to stop accidental quit

Tags: sublimetext2

I keep hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in *Sublime Text 2*. Can I remap the *Quit* command to so that this key binding doesn't work or requires i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>?

I've tried mapping it to null -

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+q"], "command": "" }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `ctrl+q` binding from your `Key Bindings - Default` file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use Package Control to install [Maybs Quit](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Maybs%20Quit), which remaps <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> to ask whether you want to quit, close the view or window, save or do nothing:

[image]

You can then quit by typing <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

It's an old question, but still :

In *MacOS* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) is <kbd>Super</kbd> so the solution is this :

```
{ "keys": ["super+q"], "command": "noop" }
```

Comment: This worked for me on OS X. On Windows it looks like `super` maps to the Windows key: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#modifiers

Answer (score 12):

I believe you need to give it some command. An entry with an empty command is ignored. Try doing

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+q"], "command": "noop" }
]
```

Comment: Hi skuroda - I've tried that approach but unfortunately it doesn't work. I think this might be something I have to handle in the OS.

Answer (score 12):

I remapped the quit to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>:

```
{ "keys": ["super+q"], "command": "noop" },
{ "keys": ["super+alt+q"], "command": "exit" }
```

Comment: I like this one best.